# What dp should I use for Android icons?

Tags: android, icons

I found this [LINK](http://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/chart/android/) that outlines what dimensions of images/icons/notifications/etc in Android should be. I then looked for some solid standard icons and stumbled upon Google's [REPOSITORY](https://www.google.com/design/icons/). Each icon exists in 18, 24, 36, and 48dp. I can then download each image for mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, and xxxhdpi.

Why do they offer the 4 different dp's if for each of the dp's I get the icon for all 6 folders (mdpi, hdpi, etc)? Also, which dp is the best? Should I use 48 simply because it's the most crisp?

Comment: The different folders (mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, and xxxhdpi) caters to different screen sizes of phones and tablets and so on if I'm not wrong.

Comment: That's true. My question is, why does Google offer 18, 24, 36, and 48dp versions of the icons -f for each of those densities, there are then 6 different icons (one for each folder)? What is the point of the 18/24/36/48? (I updated the question, hopefully it's more clear now)

Comment: Different phones have different screen resolutions and dpi. Probably to cater to them. Loading an image with the max 48dp is probably the thing to do , but we have to take into considerations the processing power of the phone if your application is image intensive. A new phone would probably do fine, but phones which are in the lower-tier may suffer in performance.

Comment: Futhermore, a phone which as less dpi, cant display those crisp images which your 48dp can offer. So you are limited by the hardware side too. You have to see which target of consumers you're targeting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Size which you pick from [this](https://www.google.com/design/icons/) is image size. Each folder inside, is that image, with that size, scaled to proper resolution for each device type screen size (`mdpi`, `hdpi`, `xhdpi`, `xxhdpi`, `xxxhdpi`).

Which size you will use, it's your choice (or [Material Design](https://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/metrics-keylines.html), if you decide to follow these rules).

Comment: That makes 100% sense. I got so wraped up in densities, I didn't realize they meant that many dp on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

The key here is to support multiple screens and different densities.
Almost every application should have alternative drawable resources for different screen densities, because almost every application has a launcher icon and that icon should look good on all screen densities. Likewise, if you include other bitmap drawables in your application (such as for menu icons or other graphics in your application), you should provide alternative versions or each one, for different densities.

To create alternative bitmap drawables for different densities, you should follow the 3:4:6:8:12:16 scaling ratio between the six generalized densities.

[image: Relative sizes for bitmap drawables that support each density.]

A set of six generalized densities:

- ldpi (low) ~120dpi
- mdpi (medium) ~160dpi
- hdpi (high) ~240dpi
- xhdpi (extra-high) ~320dpi
- xxhdpi (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi
- xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high) ~640dpi

For more information, please refer to the [developer site](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Answer (score 1):

18dp is for small contextual icons

24dp is for notification icons

36dp is for action bar, dialog & tab icons

48dp is for launcher icons