# Android : Connection between icon size and dp?

Tags: android, icons, android-icons

I created following chart using [Iconhandbook](http://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/chart/android/) reference.

```
+----------+-----------+--------------+
| Launcher | Actionbar | Notification |
|----------|-----------|--------------|
|    48    |     24    |      22      |
|    72    |     36    |      33      |
|    96    |     48    |      44      |
|   144    |     72    |      66      |
|   196    |     96    |      88      |
+----------+-----------+--------------+
```

Also I found that when changing dp from 24dp to 36dp and 36dp to 48dp. Icon size increase in `size + 6px`.

```
24dp    =>   36dp 
     [12 + 6]
24px   [12]  36px  [18]    
36px   [12]  54px  [18]
48px   [12]  72px  [18]
72px   [24]  108px [36]   
96px   [24]  144px [36]
```

How these sizes change according to dp (18dp, 24dp ...). Specially notification icons?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What dp should I use for Android icons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31330819/what-dp-should-i-use-for-android-icons)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309354/formula-px-to-dp-dp-to-px-android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16679526/android-scaling-density-issues